# Redux Form - how to disable sync/async validation with a flag

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, redux-form, react-redux-form

I am looking for the most non invasive way to disable validation of redux form for dev/debug purposes
I have a wizard form similar to the tutorial https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/examples/wizard/ but I am using field validators plus an async validator
I would still like to display errors but be able to proceed to the next wizard step even when validation fails
I would like to add a flag to the url like ?ignore-validation=true (using react router)

here is a fragment of my wizard step1:

```
export class CustomerStep1 extends React.PureComponent<FormProps> {
    render(): React.Node {
            const {
                handleSubmit,
            } = this.props;

            const submit = handleSubmit(createValidateCardAction);

            return (
                    <form onSubmit={submit}>

                                    <Field
                                        name="card_number"
                                        placeholder="7777 1234 5678 9012"
                                        component={Input}
                                        validate={cardNumber}
                                    />
...

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'customerWizard',
    destroyOnUnmount: false,
    forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true,
})(CustomerStep1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two possibilities here:

1) Split your wizard forms in more than one form and validate them separately. You could create another state to control which form you want to show. Even though it has more states to manage, I would pick that one.

2) You could leave just the async validation for each field and throw the errors there. Also, You must create a state to manage the page and manage it inside the async validation functions. I create an example of this second approach: https://codesandbox.io/s/o46k8lx7kz